# Is there a way to convert Rd file online on github to pdf

Tags: r, github, rstudio, rd

I am trying to convert a Rd file to a Pdf so I can read it.
This is the link to the Rd file:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helske/walker/master/man/walker_glm.Rd

I am new to R studio so please if there any package I need to load let me know.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: you could just install the package then `help('walker', help_type = 'pdf')` will generate and save a pdf of just that man page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file `walker_glm.Rd` and run

```
system("R CMD Rd2pdf walker_glm.Rd")
```

This will create `walker_glm.pdf`.